# Inserting characters around a part of a string?

Tags: r, string, gsub

I'm looking to wrap parts of a string in R, following certain rules, in a vectorised way.

Put simply, if I had a vector:

`c("x^2", "x^2:z", "z", "x:z", "z:x:b", "z:x^2:b")`

the function would sweep through each element and wrap `I()` around those parts where there is an exponent, resulting in the following output:

`c("I(x^2)", "I(x^2):z", "z", "x:z", "z:x:b", "z:I(x^2):b")`

I've tried various approaches where I first split by : and then gsub, but this isn't particularly scalable.

Comment: you could look into `gsub`

Comment: `gsub("(.)\\^", ("I(\\1^"), gsub("\\^(.)", ("^\\1)"), strngs))`, with `strngs` being your vector

Comment: @dario - should be able to simplify that to two capture groups - `gsub("([^:]+)(\\^2)", "I(\\1\\2)", x)` maybe, though not sure how robust it would be.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These seem reasonably general.  They don't assume that the variable in the complex fields must be named  `x` but handle any names made of word characters and also don't assume that the arithmetic expression must be an exponential but handle any arithmetic expression that includes non-word characters.  for example, they would surround `y+pi` with I(...).

**1)** This one liner captures each field and processes it using the indicated function, expressed in formula notation.  It surrounds each field that contains a non-word character with I(...) .  It works with any variables whose names are made from word character.

```
library(gsubfn)

gsubfn("[^:]+", ~ if (grepl("\\W", x)) sprintf("I(%s)", x) else x, s)
## [1] "I(x^2)"     "I(x^2):z"   "z"          "x:z"        "z:x:b"     
## [6] "z:I(x^2):b"
```

**2)** This surrounds any field containing a character that is not :, letter or number with I(...)

```
gsub("([^:]*[^:[:alnum:]][^:]*)", "I(\\1)", s)
## [1] "I(x^2)"     "I(x^2):z"   "z"          "x:z"        "z:x:b"     
## [6] "z:I(x^2):b"
```

**3)** In this alternative we split the strings at colon, then surround  fields containing a non-word character with I(...) and paste them back together.

```
surround <- function(x) ifelse(grepl("\\W", x), sprintf("I(%s)", x), x)
s |> 
  strsplit(":") |>
  sapply(function(x) paste(surround(x), collapse = ":"))
## [1] "I(x^2)"     "I(x^2):z"   "z"          "x:z"        "z:x:b"     
## [6] "z:I(x^2):b"
```

### Note

The input used is the following:

```
s <- c("x^2", "x^2:z", "z", "x:z", "z:x:b", "z:x^2:b")
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below?

```
> gsub("(x(\\^\\d+))", "I(\\1)", c("x^2", "x^2:z", "z", "x:z", "z:x:b", "z:x^2:b"))
[1] "I(x^2)"     "I(x^2):z"   "z"          "x:z"        "z:x:b"     
[6] "z:I(x^2):b"
```